# Python - Incomplete Legend on Subplots

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to add some legends to two subplots while analysing my target variable. Once I manually add the legends I can only see the first letter on each of the charts.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(20,10))
# Normal distplot for SalePrice
normal = sns.distplot(target,  ax=ax[0])
normal.set_title('Normal SalePrice Distribution')
norm_mu, norm_sigma = norm.fit(target)
norm_legend = 'Normal dist. ($\mu=$ {:.2f} and $\sigma=$ {:.2f} 
)'.format(norm_mu, norm_sigma)
normal.legend(norm_legend)

# Log Transformation
target_log = np.log(target)
log_transform = sns.distplot(target_log, ax=ax[1])
log_transform.set_title('Log Transformed SalePrice Distribution')
log_mu, log_sigma = norm.fit(target)
log_legend = 'Log dist. ($\mu=$ {:.2f} and $\sigma=$ {:.2f} 
)'.format(log_mu, log_sigma)
log_transform.legend(log_legend)
```

[image: Target Variable]

Any ideas why this can be happening?

Comment: try wrapping `norm_legend` in a list. side note, `target` is undefined in your script. you should define it (with a call to e.g. `numpy.random.<dist>` so that your example is runable for people trying to help you.

Comment: check the docs for why `norm_legend` needs to be a list: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html

Comment: Thanks for the response @PaulH! Yes, target is not initialized in this script but was to give a sense of what I'm trying to do.  I'll wrap those legends in a list!